# ubuntu 14.04 mounting usb with "can't read superblock "

Tags: usb, mount

My usb was working pretty normally and now it is unable to open showing the following message:

```
Error mounting /dev/sdb1 at /media/sooraj/7D64-9145: Command-line `mount -t "vfat" -o "uhelper=udisks2,nodev,nosuid,uid=1002,gid=1002,shortname=mixed,dmask=0077,utf8=1,showexec,flush" "/dev/sdb1" "/media/sooraj/7D64-9145"' exited with non-zero exit status 32: mount: /dev/sdb1: can't read superblock
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to repair your filesystem. You can do it with `testdisk`:

```
sudo apt-get install testdisk
sudo testdisk

>Create a new log file
[Choose Disk]
>Intel/PC partition
>Advanced
[Choose Partition]
>Boot
>Repair FAT
[Accept Defaults and Write]
>(Q)uit until exited
```

[Source link here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2103994)

Comment: thank you....even though i couldn't repair it, i could take the backup